# convert image into a javascript file with raphael

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, raphael

convert image into a js file

I use raphael.js for some javascript stuff and it is pretty helpful but when I go to this demo:

http://raphaeljs.com/tiger.html

He has made a tiger with of javascript to create a svg image, I'm pretty sure he didn't write that code himself (http://raphaeljs.com/tiger.js) how did he made that code with raphael.js?

Comment: could possibly use http://www.readysetraphael.com/ on an svg file.

Comment: or http://flarnie.com/2013/javascript/svg-to-raphael-js/

Comment: Thanks, have successfully converted my images